# Chiqset Problem: Assigned data ... must be compatible with existing data

Tags: r

For my thesis i have to do a CHI-SQUARE TEST.
Right at the beginning this comes:

```
> # Creates new variables that aggregate categories we need for the hypothesis testing
> ## For H1 and H2 (note that hate otheraddressed is excluded because it is not related to the YouTuber itself)
> chisqset$hate_total <- chisqset$hate_sexual + chisqset$hate_sexist + chisqset$hate_violent + chisqset$hate_other
Error in `$<-`:
! Assigned data `... + chisqset$hate_other` must be compatible with existing data.
✖ Existing data has 755 rows.
✖ Assigned data has 0 rows.
ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
Caused by error in `vectbl_recycle_rhs_rows()`:
! Can't recycle input of size 0 to size 755.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
Warnmeldungen:
1: Unknown or uninitialised column: `hate_sexual`. 
2: Unknown or uninitialised column: `hate_sexist`. 
3: Unknown or uninitialised column: `hate_violent`. 
4: Unknown or uninitialised column: `hate_other`.
```

Does anyone maybe knows where's the problem or where it can be?

I try to set up a chiqset

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.